# When creating an NSAlert in Objective C, will I need to release the NSAlert?

Tags: objective-c

So I made a function:

```
void alertErr(const char *const message, const char *const info) {
    NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
    alert.alertStyle = NSAlertStyleCritical;
    alert.messageText = @(message);
    alert.informativeText = @(info);
    [alert runModal];
}
```

Usually there is some form of `@AutoReleasePool` or something I do not know, but does my function contain a memory leak? Also is there any reason doing this rather than doing this in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have ARC enabled (which has been the default for new projects for years), then you don't need to release the `NSAlert`. In fact the code will not compile if you try to, because you are not allowed to send the `release` message when ARC is enabled.

If you have ARC disabled, then yes, you should `[alert release]` after you `[alert runModal]`. You need to `release` because you became an owner of it when you sent the `alloc` message.

Read more in “Memory-Management Rules” in the [Cocoa Core Competencies](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html) guide.

If your project already contains Swift code, then there is no particular reason to use Objective-C instead of Swift to create this alert.

If your project doesn't already contain Swift code, then adding your first Swift code to the project may increase your compile times more than you want. Objective-C typically compiles much faster than Swift.

Comment: Is it easier to bridge Objective C to pure C, also is it faster or slower?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Easier than what?

Comment: To my experience, it is easier to bridge ObjC to C than Swift to C, also, I hear Swift is faster than ObjC, but would it be in this case?